# Google street view launched from within iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

Does anyone have a snippet of code to launch the Google Maps App in streetview mode from within my iPad app.

I want to add a button to one of my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation ([Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1)), jumping into Street View is not supported.

Comment: So it will launch the maps application but not directly into street view is that correct?